# Splitting and then combining streams with RX

Tags: concurrency, rxjs, rx-java, rx-java2, system.reactive

I'm looking for some kind of a best practice or pattern to handle the following case:

I have two streams that I want to combine in the following way:

```
                               |-------------|
                               | Transform A |------------>|---------|
              |---------|----->|-------------|             |         |
Stream A----->| Split A |                                  | Combine |-------> ?
              |---------|----->|--------------------|      |   All   |
                               | Transform and      |      |         |
                               | Combine A (latest) |----->|---------|
                               | and B (latest)     |
Stream B---------------------->|--------------------|
```

Stream A and B are producing events asynchronously. I'd like to combine latest from A and B and combine the result with the result of a computation on top of A.

When an event in B is received, the whole pipeline runs with the value from this event and the latest from A.

Is there an elegant way to make sure that when an event in A is received, the **Combine All** runs with events that are based on this event from A and avoid a race condition between **Transform A** and **Transform and Combine A and B**

Comment: It really depends on what behavior you want when only `A` or only `B` emits. Otherwise `withLatestFrom` or `combineLatest` should be what you're looking for.

Comment: When only B arrives I want to combine with the latest from A. When only A arrives, I want the latest from B, with the current from A, but I need to avoid race condition, resulting in combining current value of A with a computation based on previous value of A.

Comment: yeah, but what if `B` arrives and there's no `A` yet?

Comment: In that case I'm OK with the standard behavior of with latest from. I'm less concerned with this issue and more with the issue of getting the same version of A in the two derived streams that are based on A

Comment: @davidrac - Are you expecting paired events from `a` and `b`, but they might come at different times?

Comment: Yes, A and B may produce events at different times, and I'm fine with using combine latest for them. My concern with combine latest is about combining two events with different versions of A.

Comment: @davidrac - It won't use different versions of `A`. That's how Rx works. You also can use `Publish(x => ...)` to share a single subscription of `A`.

Comment: @davidrac - I'm still wanting to confirm that `a` and `b` are paired - so if you get 50 values from `a` you will also get `50` (not more and not less) from `b`? They just might come at different times?

Comment: A and B are not paired. They may fire at different times, and at different frequencies. regarding using different versions of A - if `TransformA` and `Combine A and B` are both async and may take arbitrary time, and `combineAll` is combining latest, isn't there a risk that the combination will be based on different versions of A? I can't see how that would work.

Comment: Viewing your picture as a graph, I guess your problem is that there is a diamond in it, and you are trying to avoid getting a double update at the leaf node of your diamond. It's pretty difficult to achieve this with rx out of the box. You can manipulate schedulers and debounce to get this behaviour. I've started experimenting with a library to do this here: https://github.com/tonicsoft/dataflow It's not really ready to be consumed but it might give you some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by combining a single threaded scheduler with the debounce operator:

```
class ManualExecutor : Executor {
    private val tasks = ArrayDeque<Runnable>()

    override fun execute(command: Runnable) = tasks.push(command)

    fun runAllTasks() {
        while (tasks.isNotEmpty()) {
            tasks.pop().run()
        }
    }
}

val a: Observable<A>
val b: Observable<B>

val scheduler = Schedulers.from(ManualExecutor())

val aTransformed = a.observeOn(scheduler).map { transformA(it) }
val aCombinedWithB = combine(a, b).observeOn(scheduler)

val final = combine(aTransformed, aCombinedWithB).debounce(0)

// some time later....
emitA() // now all the updates are queued in our ManualExecutor
scheduler.runAllTasks() // final will only emit once, not twice!
```

This won't compile out of the box of course and you'll have to fiddle with the scheduler and tests to get it right, but maybe the idea will help. If using debounce with a "zero" timeout feels a bit too hacky, you can also use the other signature which allows full control over the debounce period with an observable.

However, if your intended usage is not the general case and is specific only to the above, then you can simplify the problem away by with something similar to this:

```
              |-----------------------|
Stream A----->| map A to              |
              | pair(A, transform(A)) |                 
              |-----------------------|                 
                        |                               
                        |----->|--------------------|   
                               | Combine A, t(A)    |   
                               | and B (latest)     |--> ?
                               | into 3-tuple       |
Stream B---------------------->|--------------------|
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Observable.Publish(source, x => ...)` ensures that you have only one subscription to `source` but you can use it, as the variable `x` as many times as you like. It ensures you never get any race conditions on the `source`.

You could use it like this:

```
Func<A, C> transform_A = a => ...;
Func<A, B, D> combine_A_and_B = (a, b) => ...;
Func<C, D, E> combine_all = (c, d) => ...;

IObservable<A> stream_a = ...;
IObservable<B> stream_b = ...;

IObservable<E> query =
    stream_a
        .Publish(stream_a_published =>
        {
            var stream_c = stream_a_published.Select(transform_A);
            var stream_d = stream_a_published.CombineLatest(stream_b, combine_A_and_B);
            return stream_c.CombineLatest(stream_d, combine_all);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the latest comment of @tonicsoft, is the idea is to have something like that:

```java
Flowable<Pair<Long, String>> streamPairA = Flowable.interval(3, SECONDS)
                                                   .doOnNext(l -> System.out.println("new value of A: " + l))
                                                   .map(l -> new Pair<>(l, "Hello " + l));
Flowable<Long> streamB = Flowable.interval(5, SECONDS)
                                 .doOnNext(l -> System.out.println("new value of B: " + l));

Flowable.combineLatest(streamPairA, streamB, (x, y) -> "--> " + x.value()
                                                        + " (latest A: " + x.key() + ", latest B: " + y + ")")
        .subscribe(System.out::println);

Flowable.timer(1, MINUTES) // Just to block the main thread for a while
        .blockingSubscribe();
```