# Split a stream, edit its fields then recombine it to a single stream

Tags: java, kotlin, concurrency, rx-java2

I have the following structure

```
           --- Stream A [ A.map1.diff() ] ---
          |                                     |
          |                                     |
Source --- --- Stream B [ B.map5.diff() ] --- --- combineLatest(A,B,C)
          |                                     |
          |                                     |
           --- Stream C [ C.map9.diff() ] ---
```

The source always emits the current total values for all maps. The individual streams should only emit the differences of their respective maps.
The diff functions are flowable extentions that definitely work (used at some other places). The diff does not emit if there is no change.

Now let's assume map9 had differences. The combineLatest will now have the updated values for map9, however map1 and map5 still have the origin state from when the flowables were first created, which means all values at the point of creating, since we first need all values before we can differentiate. When map5 has a difference it's the same with map1 and map9.

It is as if there are three separate instances of the combineLatest block for each Stream and each only has the updated values for their respective map.

The problem is now that each update emitted by combineLatest is huge because it's essentially always just all the values sans the one that triggered it.

I already looked at [Splitting and then combining streams with RX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60363508/splitting-and-then-combining-streams-with-rx) and [Recombining elements from the same reactive stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58916702/recombining-elements-from-the-same-reactive-stream) (different language I know) to try and solve this, but wasn't successful.

Edit: This is part of a socket connection construct which I cannot change.
There is a root flowable that all connections share and an individual subscription flowable for each connection. I'll add an abstract of how it looks.

Edit2: I am not married to the idea to split the flowable stream. If there is a way where I can edit the fields of `FlowAgg` without splitting it, for example by doing it one by one, I am happy to take that as well.

Excerpt:

```
data class FlowAgg(
    val devices: Map<Int, Device),
    val assignments: Map<Int, Assignment),
    val systemtime: Map<Int, Timestamp)
)
data class Summary(
    val id: Int,
    val device: Device? = null,
    val assigment: Assignment? = null,
    val systemtime: Timestamp? = null
)

[...]

socketTopic(
    path = "/summary",
    root = { _ ->
        Flowables.combineLatest(
            DeviceFlowable,
            AssignmentFlowable,
            SystemtimeFlowable
        ) { devices, assignments, systemtime ->
            FlowAgg(
                devices = devices,
                assignments= assignments,
                systemtime = systemtime ,
            )
        },
    subscription = { broadcast ->
        broadcast
            .publish { flow -> // flow: Flowable<FlowAgg>
                Flowables.combineLatest(
                    flow.map { it.devices }.diff(),
                    flow.map { it.assignments }.diff(),
                    flow.map { it.systemTime }.diff()
                ) { devices, assignments, systemTime ->
                    val keys = devices.keys + assignments.keys + systemTime.keys
                    keys.map {
                        Summary(
                            id = it,
                            devices = devices[it],
                            assignments = devices[it],
                            systemtime = devices[it]
                        )
                }
                .map {
                    Json.encodeToString(ListSerializer(Summary.serializer()), it)
                }
            }
    }
)
```

Comment: There are multiple things I don't understand about your situation. First being, why would you want to have a source which produce a stream where you have 3 different entities which get processed in a different manner and why on earth do you want to return the result again in one stream instead starting and ending in separate streams?

Comment: What does the diff function do?

Comment: Overall please provide more information, because I can sketch you multiple pipelines but I would have to make multiple assumptions about the surroundings. Some class declarations would help, or do you really have to process a `Stream<Map<>>`?

Comment: Hi, the diff function is a simple flowable extension with a scan that only emits changes to the map. The reason it is built like this is twofold. The first I cannot change. It's a socket subscription construct which has a root flowable that everyone shares and a branch flowable for each subscriber. For performance reasons I gather all relevant data points in the root one and filter the data in the subscription.
The second is compression, I already had an implementation where each map had their own endpoint, but the other approach yields a way better compression ratio. I'll update the question

Comment: Which might be important. I myself do not necessarily need/want to split the stream. I just noticed that the triple `flow.map` seems to do this. I'd be very happen if I just could apply the diff function to each field of `FlowAgg` and work with the result.

Comment: I don't understand what you try to achieve here? If only one path has a diff, and the other two are in their initial state (empty to full maps), of course `combineLatest` will keep combining with 2 full maps and one diff map. You say you don't want the full maps the second time, okay, but what should happen to them?

Comment: Hi, they should also only contain their last state. I just want to take `FlowAgg`, do a diff on all three maps it cointains and get a new `FlowAgg` with just the changes. I could do an extention function for `<FlowAgg>Flowable` and handle it manually, but I'd like a more generic approach.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the culprit for my problem of parallel executions of the combineLatest Block. The separate publish caused the split in, I presume, thread context.

It now behaves as expected.

I changed the subscription as follows:

```kotlin
subscription = { broadcast ->
        Flowables.combineLatest(
            broadcast.map { it.devices }.diff(),
            broadcast.map { it.assignments }.diff(),
            broadcast.map { it.systemTime }.diff()
        ) { devices, assignments, systemTime ->
            FlowAgg(devices, assignments, systemTime)
        }
        .debounce(5, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .map { (devices, assignments, systemTime) ->
            val keys = devices.keys + assignments.keys + systemTime.keys
            keys.map {
                Summary(
                    id = it,
                    devices = devices[it],
                    assignments = devices[it],
                    systemtime = devices[it]
               )
        }
        .map {
            Json.encodeToString(ListSerializer(Summary.serializer()), it)
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: I also changed the diff function to accept flag that singals it to also emit an emptyMap on no changes and replaced combineLatest with zip and removed the debounce. This works very well:

```kotlin
subscription = { broadcast ->
        Flowables.zip(
            broadcast.map { it.devices }.diff(),
            broadcast.map { it.assignments }.diff(),
            broadcast.map { it.systemTime }.diff()
        ) { devices, assignments, systemTime ->
            FlowAgg(devices, assignments, systemTime)
        }
        .map { (devices, assignments, systemTime) ->
            val keys = devices.keys + assignments.keys + systemTime.keys
            keys.map {
                Summary(
                    id = it,
                    devices = devices[it],
                    assignments = devices[it],
                    systemtime = devices[it]
               )
        }
        .map {
            Json.encodeToString(ListSerializer(Summary.serializer()), it)
        }
    }
}
```